# Why isn't this program showing any number above 3?

Tags: c

Wrote this to find the prime numbers between `2` to `1000`. But it stops after showing that `2` and `3` are prime numbers. I know I can find how to write a code for finding out prime numbers on the internet. But I really need to know what's going wrong here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int i, j;
    int ifPrime = 1;
    for (i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                ifPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ifPrime == 1) {
            printf("%d is prime\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re initialising ifPrime in the wrong place.

Comment: Read [*How to Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Debugging skills are programming skills

Comment: Note that you can dramatically speed up the inner loop by testing `j * j <= i`, which saves over 960 iterations per value when `i` is near 1000.  There also really isn’t much point in checking even numbers larger than 2; they’re not prime.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `j <= i/j` has advantages over `j * j <= i` in more general code.  It does not overflow. `j * j <= i` when `i == INT_MAX` is a infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
int ifPrime=1;
```

must be inside the outer `for` loop. There it will be initialized for every `i`. This corresponds to the natural language words "to check whether a number i is prime, first assume it is. Then check if it is divisible". The code you had before said "to check whether the numbers 2 to 1000 are prime, first assume they are", and this wording was too broad.

The code should be:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 2; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        int ifPrime = 1;
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
```

I replaced `main` with `int main` since that is required since 20 years. (You should not learn programming from such old books.)

I moved the `int i` and the `int j` into the `for` loops so that you cannot accidentally use these variables outside the scope where they have defined values.

To avoid this bug in the future, it's a good idea to extract the `is_prime` calculation into a separate function. Then you would have been forced to initialize the `ifPrime` in the correct place.

Another way of finding the cause of this bug is to step through the code using a debugger and ask yourself at every step: does it still make sense what the program is doing?

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting ifPrime back to 1 after checking for the single number. So once you get a number that is non_prime, ifPrime is now 0 and hence `if(ifPrime == 1)` would never return true post that and hence you only see 2, 3 as prime

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    for( int i=2;i<1000;i++)
    {

        int ifPrime = 1;
        for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
        {   
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                ifPrime=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(ifPrime==1)
        {
            printf("%d is prime\n",i);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```